# max_user_connections Wordpress mysql error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, connection

I have wordpress site on bluehost which is giving me database connection error frequently, I copied the site on other server and it worked fine but on blue host its giving me error. they said code is doing that so i tried custom php script and tested that user and that is also giving me same error. So what is the actual error and how to resolve.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    ?>
```

**Connection failed: User anuchwvv_live44 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections**

Answer (score 0):

This tends to happen when something is holding its own connections open. Most shared hosting limits this and does not allow you to manage it at all yourself.

If there is some custom code that is opening a connection does it ever close that connection? or just keep making new ones?

My guess is it never actually never closes those connections and keeps just making new ones and runs into this limit.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, an overly high number of connections is the result of either bugs in applications not closing connections properly or because of wrong design, like the connection to MySQL is established, but then the application is busy doing something else before closing MySQL handler. In cases where an application doesn’t close connections properly, wait_timeout is an important parameter to tune and discard unused or idle connections to minimize the number of active connections to your MySQL server – and this will ultimately help to avoid the “Too many connections” error.

Comment: Where do i put this ? because even if i dont run the wp source and just a test php file its giving me this error. also it works on other hosting fine as they provide more then 200 max number  connection